# How to log to a regular file with Log4J without using levels (warn, info, etc)?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am interested in using log4j for audit logging, in other words, I will open my own file and start logging anything I want. Therefore I do NOT want to use warn, info or any log level. Something like that:

```
Log log = new Log("blah.txt");
log.log("Test");
log.close();
```

How can I do that with LOG4J?

A concrete example that I can run will be very appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own level `AUDIT` and use that to log everything. Logging without a level might not be too easily achieved.

Comment: I am assuming this is something not supported by log4j, in other words, log4j is good for level logging but not for event sourcing where a level does not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using log4j, you don't need to re-invent the wheel.  You could just configure a FileAppender and only specify the package or class that should log to it, so nothing else does.  You're not forced to use any specific or all logging levels, just stick to one, like debug or info.  You can take it a step further and configure your FileAppender to only capture info or debug, whichever you choose.

Unless there's some value in not using what log4j already has built, I'd stick with what they have.  Could you elaborate on your use case perhaps so we understand why you don't want to use the built in functionality?

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommended to keep logging configuration outside of your code. Today you think that you have simple logging logic, however tomorrow it can become more and more complex.

Anyway, if you want a quick start and one simple `log` method - you can build a simple wrapper over **log4j** API:

```
 class Log {

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Log.class);

    public Log(String fileName) throws IOException {
        // print just message
        Layout layout = new PatternLayout("%m");
        // log to file
        FileAppender appender = new FileAppender(layout, fileName, true);
        logger.addAppender(appender);
        logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
    }

    public void log(String string) {
        logger.info(string);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Log log = new Log("test.log.txt");
            log.log("Test message");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```